# Using List.map with should throw Exception

Tags: f#, functional-programming, nunit, functional-testing

```
let d5=["IIII";"VVVV";"XXXX";"LLLL";"MMMM"] 

[<Test; ExpectedException(typeof<System.Exception>)>]
    member this.
        ``More than 3 times repetive characters `` ()=
        //Missing part
```

**This test isn't working**.
I have converter which parsers Rome numbers. But it works wrong for

> ["IIII";"VVVV";"XXXX";"LLLL";"MMMM"]

When you send convert("IIII") it returns 4 , but it should have given System.Exception error. I need to **write NUnit test** (not fix converter) which maps every string in the list and passes when every single of them returns error. Otherwise fails.
**The test I want to write is as following.**

```
d5=["IIII";"VVVV";"XXXX";"LLLL";"MMMM"]
convert each d5 element
if each of them is giving system.exception error 
then test is successfull
else test is failed
```

Any solution? Any idea. . 
If you are interested convert method is here [Convert Method](https://github.com/juhan/itt8060/blob/master/coursework6input/BrokenRomanNumbers/Library1.fs)

Comment: There's no implementation of your `convert` function. Maybe you forgot to add it?

Comment: i referenced it and it works fine for other tests

Comment: As there's no code then there's no way to correct the function

Comment: If you need convert function it is here https://github.com/juhan/itt8060/blob/master/coursework6input/BrokenRomanNumbers/Library1.fs

Comment: But I shouldn't fix the function. I need to write the test.

Comment: Either I didn't understood or the problem is in convert ; I c/c the github code in interactive (by the way there are a lot of warning stating that you should use `||` instead of `or`) and just tested `convert "IIII"` and it'll give 4 (as you stated) so if the function should raise an exception maybe ... the function should raise an exception (because IIII is an invalid roman number)

Comment: Converter needs to be tested. I don't fix converter. As I wrote before I need to write Nunit tests for testing converter.

Comment: As I mentioned before , my test should pass if convert every item in ["IIII";"VVVV";"XXXX";"LLLL";"MMMM"]   raise error. If convert("MMMM") doesn't raise error then the test should fail

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get. I tried to repeat your test, but getting: System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: I wanted to write a test. But as you see mine isn't working.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it is more obvious now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to test all values separately:

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

type ConvertTest() = 

    let convert s = 
        if String.length s > 3 then failwith "Something's wrong"
        else String.length s

    [<Theory>]
    member this.``More than 3 characters throws``([<Values("IIII", "VVVVVV", "XXXX", "LLLL", "MMMM")>] s) = 
        (fun () -> convert s |> ignore) |> should throw typeof<System.Exception>

    [<Theory>]
    member this.``Less than 4 characters returns length``([<Values("II", "VV", "XXX", "LLL", "MMM")>] s) = 
        convert s |> should equal s.Length
```

I deliberately changed the convert method to a slightly different implementation (as you gave none) but it should be obvious how to proceed.

Comment: Sorry, you can't change convert method. I have dll of the convert method. And I am testing it. I shared convert method in the comments, for not having  further misunderstanding I put it in the question as well. Thanks again

Comment: @EtibarHəsənov You should still be able to just use the tests as provided. I put the `convert` to make it compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TestCase` attributes to parameterize the test, and `Assert.Throws` to verify that an exception was thrown:

```
open System
open NUnit.Framework

[<TestFixture>]
type Tests() =

    [<TestCase("IIII")>]
    [<TestCase("VVVV")>]
    [<TestCase("XXXX")>]
    [<TestCase("LLLL")>]
    [<TestCase("MMMM")>]
    member this.ThrowsOnInvalidInput (cand : string) =
        Assert.Throws<Exception> (fun () -> convert cand |> ignore) |> ignore
```

Comment: Is there any possiblity of cand being list of strings? like: let cand=["IIII";"VVVV";"XXXX";"LLLL";"MMMM"]  .